# Need to create sub-arrays from one big array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Please help me to solve one problem that I am really stuck in PHP

I have one big array

```
$a = array(
    'foo_1' => 'Dog',
    'bar_1' => 'Cat',
    'baz_1' => 'Fish',
    'foo_2' => 'Frog',
    'bar_2' => 'Bug',
    'baz_2' => 'Ddd',
    ...
);
```

and it needs to be transformed in multiple arrays:

```
$a_1 = array(
    'foo' => 'Dog',
    'bar' => 'Cat',
    'baz' => 'Fish'
);  

$a_2 = array(
    'foo' => 'Frog',
    'bar' => 'Bug',
    'baz' => 'Ddd'
);
```

As you noticed there is a small logic. The big array should be splited by sets of keys ( _1,_2,_3 ; _1,_2,_33 )

Hope I was clear enough!

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? We can help you fix your code but you should try to solve it yourself first.

Comment: hows is the original array created? Wouldn't a multidimensional array make more sense?

Comment: your original array has duplicate keys, which cannot be happening! foo_1 is duplicated for example.

Comment: Your main array doesn't agree with the computer science laws :)

Comment: Sorry guys ... my mistake. I changed the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$a` has this structure (because OP original array has duplicate keys):

```
$a = array(
'foo_1' => 'Dog',
'bar_1' => 'Cat',
'baz_1' => 'Fish',
'foo_2' => 'Frog',
'bar_2' => 'Bug',
'baz_2' => 'Ddd'
);
```

You can transform array by this approach:

```
$temp = array();
foreach($a as $key=>$val){
    $num = substr(strrchr($key, '_'), 1);
    $nkey = basename($key, '_'.$num);
    $temp[$num][$nkey] = $val;
}
// See what happens
print_r($temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the key always repeat every **3** items *and* they are ordered, `array_chunk` would work:

```
$newArray = array_chunk($a, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you , this is good for sake of simplicity , but i need more flexibility ! cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure a multidimensional array is better but this is what you asked for, values with the same string before "_" will get overwritten (lost) so there is probably an issue with your logic.

```
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();
$array3 = array();
$bigArray = array('av_1'=>'dghdfg','ab_2'=>'dgdfg');
foreach($bigArray as $key=>$value)
{
  $splitKey = explode('_',$key);
  $number = $splitKey[1];
  $newKey = $splitKey[0];
  $varName = "array".$number;
  ${$varName}[$newKey] = $value;
}
```

**Multidimensional:**

```
    $newBigArray = array();
    $bigArray = array('av_1'=>'dghdfg','ab_2'=>'dgdfg');

    foreach($bigArray as $key=>$value)
    {
      $splitKey = explode('_',$key);
      $newKey = $splitKey[0];
      $number = $splitKey[1];

      if(!isset($newBigArray[$newKey])) {
        $newBigArray[$newKey] = array();
      }
      $newBigArray[$newKey][$number] = $value;
    }
    var_dump($newBigArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the keys of all array entries, split them by the underscore character (_), and then put them into an array.

```
$a = array(
    'foo_1' => 'Dog',
    'bar_2' => 'Cat',
    'baz_3' => 'Fish',
    'foo_1' => 'Frog',
    'bar_2' => 'Bug',
    'baz_3' => 'Ddd',
    ...
);

$arrays = array(
    'foo' => array(),
    'bar' => array(),
    'baz' => array()
);

foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    $s = explode("_", $k);
    if (!isset($arrays[$s[0]])) {
        $arrays[$s[0]] = array();
    }
    $arrays[$s[0]][$s[1]] = $v; // This line if you want to preserve the index (1, 2, ...)
    $arrays[$s[0]][] = $v; // Or this line if you want to reindex the arrays.
    // Comment or remove one of these two lines.
}
```

Then you have a multidimensional array:

```
array(
    'foo' => array(
       "Dog",
       "Frog"
    ),
    'bar' => array(
        "Cat",
        "Bug"
    ),
    'baz' => array(
        "Fish",
        "Ddd"
    ),
    ...
)
```

I suggest you use the multidimensional array above, but if you want to make a new variable for each *'key'* (like 'foo', 'bar', et cetera), then use the following snippet:

```
$a = array(
    'foo_1' => 'Dog',
    'bar_2' => 'Cat',
    'baz_3' => 'Fish',
    'foo_1' => 'Frog',
    'bar_2' => 'Bug',
    'baz_3' => 'Ddd',
    ...
);

foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    $s = explode("_", $k);
    ${$s[0]}[$s[1]] = $v; // This line if you want to preserve the index (1, 2, ...)
    ${$s[0]}[] = $v; // Or this line if you want to reindex the arrays.
    // Comment or remove one of these two lines.
}
```

---

*Notice that your array `$a` has some duplicate keys, which is not possible in PHP.*
**EDIT:** I saw you resolved it.